Creating a struct similar to AnyHashable
I've just updated to Xcode 16 and my project is littered with warnings due to the change to mark AnyHashable as not-sendable. I was relying on AnyHashable throughout my app, creating a ViewModel layer that returned a datasource of type UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Int, AnyHashable>. Now i'm trying to build something that is Hashable and Sendable, and can be slotted in without much refactoring. Going off other examples online I created this new struct modeled after AnyHashable
public struct AnyHashableSendable: Hashable, Sendable {
    
    public let base: any Hashable & Sendable
    
    public init<H>(_ base: H) where H : Hashable {
        self.base = base
    }
    
    public static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        AnyHashable(lhs.base) == AnyHashable(rhs.base)
    }
    
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        base.hash(into: &hasher)
    }
}

But this current implementation comes with a few annoyances that i'm looking to resolve in a way that matches the apple implementation

If I have a variable foo of type AnyHashable and I want to cast it, I can simply do let newBar = foo as? bar. But with a variable of type AnyHashableSendable I now must call the property base to achieve the same, like so let newBar = foo.base as? bar. How does the inbuilt AnyHashable avoid the need to call its base property?

If I define an array or 2d array of AnyHashable ([AnyHashable], [[AnyHashable]]) I can append any struct that conforms to hashable and it will automatically cast it. E.g.


var array: [AnyHashable] = []
array.append(FooBar(prop1: "test", prop2: "test"))

But with AnyHashableSendable, each item must be initialised as the new object type, e.g.
var array: [AnyHashableSendable] = []
array.append(.init(FooBar(prop1: "test", prop2: "test")))



I've tried to solve at least the second one by creating my own custom collection type, with overridden functions that accept AnyHashable and simply call the init and store it. While it works, the differences require a decent bit of refactoring and annoying custom code/types instead of the existing logic were used too. Is there a way i'm unaware of to solve these two issues so that my new type functions like the existing AnyHashable?

Both of the behaviours of AnyHashable you mentioned are built into the compiler. You cannot create your own type that acts like this without forking the compiler.

@Sweeper its a shame swear words are banned on stackoverflow. Thanks for your help, i'll try find someone to complain too about this change

It is not possible to create such a type yourself. Both behaviours you mentioned (downcasting directly, and implicit conversion to AnyHashable) are built into the compiler directly.

From the documentation on dynamic casting in the Swift GitHub repo,  AnyHashable behaves like an existential type in the context of casting, even though it is a struct. The cast operator can "reach inside" the existential "box" and get the actual value wrapped in there.
You can find a special case for AnyHashable in DynamicCast.cpp, there is a call to _swift_anyHashableDownCastConditionalIndirect. This function is where the "reaching in to the box" happens. See its declaration in AnyHashable.swift.

For the implicit conversion to AnyHashable, the compiler inserts a compiler intrinsic function called _convertToAnyHashable, which is also declared in AnyHashable.swift, and I think this is the line that emits it.

I encountered the same issue, and I came up with this solution:
struct AnySendableHashable: @unchecked Sendable, Hashable {
    private let wrapped: AnyHashable
    
    init(_ base: some Hashable & Sendable) {
        self.wrapped = .init(base)
    }
}

So, the assumption is, that when we initialise a AnyHashable with a value conforming to Hashable and Sendable, then the resulting "Box" (AnyHashable) becomes Sendable as well.
I appreciate comments, whether this is legal, or when there are potential pitfalls with this solution.

with wrapped being private how do you access the underlying value? E.g. given an array of these AnySendableHashable, how do you iterate the array and cast the value like let obj = item as? AccountsHeaderObject, where item is a value at a given index in the array?

You use a AnySendableHashable  value  as a key in a dictionary, for example. Since it's conforming to Hashable, it's all you need to do. The comparison function is already implemented by AnyHashable. So, what AnySendableHashable is doing is reusing the hashable behaviour and just adding the sendable conformance, due to ensuring the actual value (aka base) is also a sendable. You would never need to access wrapped.

IMHO, it's not the intended use case for AnyHashable to extract the wrapped value out from it at a later point. The sole purpose of AnyHashable is to type-erase the value, and so creating a kind of  "polymorphic" type, which can be used as a key in associative containers, like Dictionary. That way, you get a dictionary with polymorphic keys.

“Not intended use case to extract the wrapper” - I’m sorry that’s complete BS. Diffable data source requires the value conform to hashable. It’s a well known workaround to use AnyHashable for that to make it generic

Well, AnyHashable has some implicit conversion capabilities, which is not available for other types in the language. So, an assignment from the wrapped type is legal syntax. For unwrapping, you can use the as operator. This requires support from the Swift runtime and the compiler. So, AnyHashable is unique in this regard. You can make wrapped public, if you need. A diffabel data source requires a Hashable value, not necessarily a AnyHashable. However, we are concerned because the solution was intended to work around the Sendable issue.
